# Non-strict equality comparisons

Tags: php, git, symfony

Today I was exploring the symfony repo and found some pull requests by @Seldaek where he switched the variable with the value as you can see bellow:

[image]

[Link for the PR](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/commit/27c53fab66adab059b6d92bfe32e3b68dd9dd04e)

What's the difference between having `$var === true` and `true === $var`?

Comment: true == $var is called **Yoda style** - read in google or here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: What's most odd about the changes is that they didn't change the port condition around? 443 is a constant and you'd have expected them to also switch those before the $port variable... unless this was done in a later commit... very strange indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional difference, it's a coding style called [yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

People use it to avoid accidental assignments in conditions which normally wouldn't be picked up by the compiler when the constant is second.

This is a valid statement, and will be difficult to debug when actually expected it to perform a comparison:

```
if ($var = 12) {}
```

This is an invalid statement and will throw an error

```
if (12 = $var) {}
```

as we cannot assign the variable to 12.